# Преобразование списка списков в граф

Tags: python, графы

Есть вот такой список (условно 3 на 3, но будет лучше если можно будет увеличить его)

```
simple_example = [
    [3, 0, 4],
    [5, 7, 1],
    [2, 6, 8]
]
```

Нужна функция, которая сможет преобразовать такой список в граф следующего вида[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запись такого графа должна выглядеть вот так

```
graph = {
    3:[{'node':5, 'price':1}, {'node':0, 'price':1}],
    0:[{'node':3, 'price':1}, {'node':7, 'price':1}, {'node':4, 'price':1}],
    4:[{'node':0, 'price':1}, {'node':1, 'price':1}],
    5:[{'node':3, 'price':1}, {'node':7, 'price':1}, {'node':2, 'price':1}],
    # и т.д
}
```

Функция должна принимать в качестве аргумента нужный нам список списков, а на выходе выдавать граф.

Я попытался найти какие-нибудь закономерности, наложил граф на систему координат, где ось ординат была перевернута (что бы совпадала с индексированием в Python). Вроде что-то есть, но много условностей.

Comment: Интересно, а значения price вы по ходу выдумывали?  В  данных задачи эта переменная не фигурирует.

Comment: А где вы искали закономерности?  Тут же простое соединение по строкам и столбцам

Comment: @passant Граф взвешенный, так я просто обозначил вес каждого ребра, он может принять любое значение, главное, чтобы у каждого ребра оно было одинаковое

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, но тогда если передать в качестве аргумента список 4 на 4, функция уже не будет работать. И я хочу, что бы функция автоматизировала процесс записи графа. Если я вас не понял, прошу, распишите подробнее.

Comment: Какая функция? Не вижу ни одной

Comment: И примера 4*4 не вижу

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я и хочу узнать как написать ту самую функцию и про то, что такой список может быть не только 3 на 3 тоже есть в вопросе.

Comment: Ну то есть функцию вы даже не пытались написать, но она «уже не будет работать».

Comment: В вопросе есть, но какой граф вы для него ожидаете вы почему-то держите в секрете

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я понял вас так как понял, поэтому и попросил объяснить подробнее если что-то не так. Какой я хочу видеть граф я так же расписал, так что с чего вы взяли, что граф 3 на 3 должен чем-то отличаться от 4 на 4 мне не понятно. Если вы видите решение, пожалуйста, расскажите о нём без лишних вопросов, которые нас только путают.

Comment: Интерполяция ожиданий по одному примеру так себе идея.  Слишком много вариантов. Поэтому и хочется ещё один пример что бы лучше понимать что именно вам надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в точном соответствии с тем, что вы написали. Если же у вас условие предполагало нечто другое, то, надеюсь, легкую модификацию задачи вам будет сделать самостоятельно не сложно:

```
simple_example = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
simp=np.array(simple_example)
n=simp.shape[0]
graph = {}
def pruff_neighbors(simp,i,j):
    neighbors=[(i-1,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1),(i+1,j)]
    nodes=[]
    for nb in neighbors:
        if (nb[0]>=0 and nb[1]>=0 and nb[0]<n and nb[1]<n):
            nodes.append(simp[nb[0],nb[1]])
    return nodes
for i in range (n):
       for j in range(n):
           print('j',j)
           nodes=pruff_neighbors(simp,i,j)
           graph[simp[i,j]]=[{'node':nb,'price':1} for nb in nodes]
print (graph)
```

Результат:

```
{1: [{'node': 2, 'price': 1}, {'node': 4, 'price': 1}], 
 2: [{'node': 1, 'price': 1}, {'node': 3, 'price': 1}, {'node': 5, 'price': 1}], 
 3: [{'node': 2, 'price': 1}, {'node': 6, 'price': 1}], 
 4: [{'node': 1, 'price': 1}, {'node': 5, 'price': 1}, {'node': 7, 'price': 1}], 
 5: [{'node': 2, 'price': 1}, {'node': 4, 'price': 1}, {'node': 6, 'price': 1}{'node': 8, 'price': 1}], 
 6: [{'node': 3, 'price': 1}, {'node': 5, 'price': 1}, {'node': 9, 'price': 1}], 
 7: [{'node': 4, 'price': 1}, {'node': 8, 'price': 1}], 
 8: [{'node': 5, 'price': 1}, {'node': 7, 'price': 1}, {'node': 9, 'price': 1}], 
 9: [{'node': 6, 'price': 1}, {'node': 8, 'price': 1}]}
```